# Display data from database in jsp form to update

Tags: sql, database

I have a table created in which there are data already entered. Now I want to edit data corresponding to an id. I am taking the Id from the user and want to select all data from database corresponding to that id. Now all the fetched data should come in a form so that I may edit it there and then save again.

I hope my question is clear. Can anyone please help me with the code and logic?

If any more information is required regarding this question, kindly ask me.

Comment: The answer to this question will involve several different software technologies.  Since you specify Java Server Pages, I assume you want to develop a web application with Java Servlets.  This question is much too broad to be answered in its present form.

Comment: Yes I am developing a web application using jsp and servlets.I just got an idea of using button.    <button type="submit" name="someName" value="someValue"><img src="someImage.png" alt="SomeAlternateText"></button> Can this be used?